# How to put the day of the function get_the_modified_date ('l', $post_id') with the first capital letter?

Tags: php

How to put the day of the function get_the_modified_date ('l') with the first capital letter?

```
echo get_the_modified_date ('l', $post_id');
```

The result is like this: "sunday

I want so: "Sunday"

Since ja I thank you

Comment: Strange...'l' should return capitalized day of the week. Can it be that css property is set this word to lowercase?

Comment: When I used mb_convert_case was for maiuscula, but I had to duplicate the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'l' will [give you](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) lowercase representation of the day. You can wrap it in `ucfirst` (and beware that you have a typo):

```
echo ucfirst( get_the_modified_date ('l', $post_id) );
```

or you can use css, if you can target it and it's the only word in there:

```
.day { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Comment: Worked, thank you